# How to remove repeated rows based on last date in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, slice, bind-rows

I have a large dataframe with many columns and rows, where lot are my sampling units (the same lot can have more than one line of information). However, new field visits are frequently made and a new table is generated, with information that may be the same, changing only the sampling date, or small changes and/or even changes in the sample size. In this case, the two tables are joined and there may be duplication of the same sampling unit, in this case I need to exclude the oldest row based on the sampling date, but I need to do this per group. I've already made some attempts, but the code doesn't work very well, sometimes it leaves old lines or repeated lines.

- Replicable example

  ```
  df1=data.frame(
  block=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6),
  units=c(1,2,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,2,3,4),
  Sector=c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  lot=c(25, 25,18 ,18 ,18 ,9,50,110,200,200,200,200),
  date= c("2019","2019","2023/10/24","2023/10/24","2023/10/24",
      "2023/09/24","2023/08/24","2023/10/24","2019", 
  "2019","2019","2019")
  )


  df2=data.frame(
  block=c(2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 6,6 ),
  units=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3,3 ),
  Sector=c(1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3),
  lot=c(18 ,18 ,18,50,200,200,200, 200),
  date= c("2023/12/24", "2023/12/24", "2023/12/24","2023/12/24",      
       "2023/11/24" ,   "2023/11/24",   "2023/11/24", "2023/11/24")
  )

  df_join<-rbind(df1, df2)

  library(tidyverse)

  df_clean<-df_join %>%
  group_by(Sector, block, lot,units ) %>%
  slice_max(date)
  ```

[image]

Comment: 1) This is a good start towards a reproducible example, however the code provided can't really be used to recreate your data set. The variables defined in creating `df1` have different numbers of rows. 2) The `date` variables in both data frames are character variables in this example. R needs to know your data is a date or datetime to sort for `slice_max`.

Comment: Make sure you are clear about what defines a group. If you use `group_by(Sector, block, lot, units)` then I see that rows 11 and 12 are in the same group because they have the same values for all 4 of those grouping columns, so deleting one of them makes sense. But Row 13 is in a group all by itself because no other row has the same values for Sector, block, lot, and units (because of the `4` in units). So maybe you only want to be grouping by 3 of those columns?

Comment: Add a column to your df_join like this: `df_join <- df_join %>% group_by(Sector, block, lot, units) %>% mutate(grp_id = cur_group_id()) %>% ungroup() %>%  arrange(block, grp_id)` , you see what @GregorThomas is referring to. And I think you misunderstand what `slice_max()` does. It returns only the maximum date per group, it's not deleting the oldest date. So for rows 11 and 12 in your example, they belong to a group of 3. The oldest date was not returned, the newest date was (n = 2). You could potentially add `%>% ungroup() %>% distinct()`. And the date in a group of 1 is both min and max!

Comment: @Gregor Tomás, You are right, but the date that interests me is only the most recent date, that is, in 2019 sample LOT 200 has 4 units and in 2023 there were only 3.

Comment: @L Tyrone, Following your tips I got the expected result, but I did it in two steps:         
  df_clean<-df_join %>%
  group_by(Sector, block, lot, units ) %>%
  distinct()%>% 
  slice_max(date)

df_clean1<-df_clean %>%
  group_by( block, lot  ) %>%
  slice_max(date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exsiting answering still has a duplicate row in the last.

The biggest problem here is that your `date` column is not regular, which is a really bad practice. Therefore, we can first try to correct it by considering `2019` as `2019/01/01` or whatever consistent as you don't have the valid data, and convert it to `date` or date time.

```
df_join['date']%<>%apply(1,FUN= function(x){if(!x%>%str_detect('\\/')) 
  x%>%str_glue("/01/01") 
  else x})%>%
  as.Date()
#OR
df_join$date = as.character(df_join$date)
df_join%<>%
  mutate(date = if_else(!date%>%str_detect('\\/'), date%>%paste0("/01/01"), date)%>%as.Date())
##track change, both should result in
> df_join$date

 [1] "2019-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2023-10-24" "2023-10-24" "2023-10-24" "2023-09-24" "2023-08-24" "2023-10-24" "2019-01-01"
[10] "2019-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-01-01" "2023-12-24" "2023-12-24" "2023-12-24" "2023-12-24" "2023-11-24" "2023-11-24"
[19] "2023-11-24" "2023-11-24"
```

Now, use the last chunk of the code your have with adding `%>% distinct()` in the end, you can get the most recent record you want.

> df_clean<-df_join %>%
> group_by(Sector, block, lot,units ) %>%
> slice_max(date) %>% distinct()

```
> df_clean
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   Sector, block, lot, units [12]
   block units Sector   lot date      
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
 1     1     1      1    25 2019-01-01
 2     1     2      1    25 2019-01-01
 3     2     1      1    18 2023-12-24
 4     2     2      1    18 2023-12-24
 5     2     3      1    18 2023-12-24
 6     3     1      3     9 2023-09-24
 7     4     1      3    50 2023-12-24
 8     5     1      3   110 2023-10-24
 9     6     1      3   200 2023-11-24
10     6     2      3   200 2023-11-24
11     6     3      3   200 2023-11-24
12     6     4      3   200 2019-01-01
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot, I added a line as distinct code() to eliminate identical lines

Comment: @Kledson Lemes Great to know that helps. I overlooked the output and will also update the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting too many columns in your `group_by`.
As far as I can tell, you want to keep the row(s) with the maximum date within each `Sector` and `block`. If the units change, you want to drop the old ones, so `units` **cannot** be in `group_by()`. If the `lot` changes, you want to drop the old ones, so `lot` **cannot** be in `group_by()`.

```
df_join %>%
  group_by(block, Sector)
  slice_max(date) %>%
  ungroup() |>
  distinct()
#    block units Sector lot       date
# 1      1     1      1  25       2019
# 2      1     2      1  25       2019
# 3      2     1      1  18 2023/12/24
# 4      2     2      1  18 2023/12/24
# 5      2     3      1  18 2023/12/24
# 6      3     1      3   9 2023/09/24
# 7      4     1      3  50 2023/12/24
# 8      5     1      3 110 2023/10/24
# 9      6     1      3 200 2023/11/24
# 10     6     2      3 200 2023/11/24
# 11     6     3      3 200 2023/11/24
```